# Simple way to typeset a two-line limit of integration

Tags: math-mode

My "limit of integration" -- "all space" -- is quite wide. Is there are simple way to put the word "space" underneath the word "all" to make the integral take up less width?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  W = \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_0 \int\limits_{\text{all space}} d\tau\,E^2\\
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: My preferred solution would be to manually adjust the spacing around the integral and leave "all space" in one line.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `\mathclap` command from the [mathtools package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  W = \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_0 \int\limits_{\mathclap{\text{all space}}} d\tau\,E^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here's another solution, which also requires loading the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package: Replace

```
\int\limits_{\text{all space}}
```

with

```
\smashoperator{\int\limits_{\text{all space}}}
```

For the use case at hand, the outputs of `\int\limits_{\mathclap{\text{all space}}}` and `\smashoperator{\int\limits_{\text{all space}}}` are identical. For use cases where only the left-hand side or the right-hand side of the limit of integration is supposed to protrude below the surrounding material, the commands `\smashoperator[r]{...}` and `\smashoperator[l]{...}` provide extra flexibility relative to what's possible with `\mathclap`, `\mathllap`, and `\mathrlap`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\substack`. However, since “all” and “space” are unlikely to clash with other parts of the equation, it makes sense to remove some width from them.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\allspace}{%
  \substack{%
    \mspace{-9mu}\mathrm{all}\mspace{-9mu}\\
    \hidewidth\mathrm{space}\hidewidth
  }%
}
   

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  W = \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_0 \int\limits_{\allspace} d\tau\,E^2\\
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I left the differential in front of the function even if my heart bleeds.

Comment: Ahahahah :-)....how the tips of xy package? :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here, I use `stackengine` to stack the limit, and a feature of it embodied in the 7th argument to `\stackengine`, given as `{T}` that uses the width of `all` to define the width of the complete stack.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  W = \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_0 \int\limits_{
  \stackengine{7pt}{\scriptsize all}{\scriptsize space}{U}{c}{F}{T}{L}
  } d\tau\,E^2\\
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]